# Mapping through JSON data that contain additional status and results from messages

Tags: reactjs, json, mapping

I'm trying to map through JSON data from React with this code...

```
import {useEffect,useState} from 'react'


function Tourapi() {

    const[tours,settour]=useState([])
    const[loading,setloading]=useState(true)

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchtour()

    },[])

    const fetchtour= async()=> {
        const furl='https://www.natours.dev/api/v1/tours'
        const res = await fetch(furl)
        const data = await res.json()
      settour(data)
      setloading(false)
    }

  if(!loading)
  {
    return (
        <div>
         {tours.map((tour)=>(

<h3> {tour.name}</h3>
         ))}   
        </div>
    )
  }
  else
  {
      return <h3>LOADING.....</h3>
  }

  
}

export default Tourapi
```

but it looks like that JSON data contain additional things and the data array so how can I Map through to get the name and description and so on...

the error that I got TypeError: tours.map is not a function

the JSON data begin with

```
{"status":"success","results":10,"data":{"data":[{"startLocation":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.185942,25.774772],"description":"Miami, USA","address":"301 Biscayne Blvd, Miami, FL 33132, USA"}
```

what I mean how can I get out of ("status":"success","results":10,"data":) and get the data its self because it's not my API to control with the response

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need, I hope it's help

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
function TourAPI() {
  const [tours, settour] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setloading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchtour();
  }, []);

  const fetchtour = async () => {
    const furl = "https://www.natours.dev/api/v1/tours";
    const res = await fetch(furl);
    const data = await res.json();
    await settour(data.data.data);
    setloading(false);
  };

  if (!loading) {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="tour-section">
          {tours.map((tours, i) => {
            return <h3 key={i}>{tours.name}</h3>;
          })}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return <h3>LOADING.....</h3>;
  }
}
export default TourAPI;
```

I'll walk you through what's in the `data`, if you `console.log(data)` in your `fetchtour`, it'll contain an object that contains properties. It's like this

`{status: 'success', results: 10, data: {data}}`

So, you want to access one more `data` inside of that `data`
That'll lead to `console.log(data.data)` to see what's in there.

And it'll appear like this.

`{data: Array(10)}`

So, the `data` key actually contains the `data`'s array inside of it, the `data.data` contains an array with 10 indexes in it as you can see. You can try in your browser to see that as well, and each index will contain the properties you want in there, which is `name`, and many more properties that you need to get like `location`, etc.

So lead us to the last `data`, if you `console.log(data.data.data)`, it'll access to `data` that contains the 10 indexes, which it'll be an array `[...]` so that we can use `map`.

That's what you need to `setState` for the `tours`

And from that, we're good to use `map`, because we actually are able to map through an array that contains indexes.
And don't forget to set `key` for each div inside the map or you'll get the warning fire out from the console in your browser.

My English is not too well so my explanation might be a little bit hard but I hope you can understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works well, and I have got your explanation so well, and I will put a key for each div, in fact, it shows me an error (Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop), thanks again to clarify the idea.

Comment: Glad it helps you, and you might want to create a `const `, something like `const tourData = data.data.data` for clearer looks, the `data.data.data` is kind of might give you confusion for later on if you want to review/watch your code in the future.

Comment: `const tourData = data.data.data` ofcourse I will..